# dynamixel_motor with catkin

Tags: ros, dynamixel-motor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear everybody,

I am starting with ROS and my objective is to create a 3D laser scanner with a Hokuyo+Dynamixel servo. The Hokuyo nodes and laser_assembler are not a problem so far. However, I have no idea how to deal with the Dynamixel servo.

I tried to follow the dynamixel_motor tutorials starting with the second tutorial, which is supposed to be done first. The problem is that the instructions are given for the previous ROS build system. I tried the same with catkin:

$ catkin_create_pkg my_dynamixel_tutorial dynamixel_controllers

But later, roscd does not recognize the new package. I tried to run $ catkin_make and this is the error:

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'my_dynamixel_tutorial'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(my_dynamixel_tutorial)
CMake Error at /home/jabuntu/Dropbox/ros_ws/devel/share/dynamixel_controllers/cmake/dynamixel_controllersConfig.cmake:154 (find_package):
Could not find module Findcontrol_msgs.cmake or a configuration file for
package control_msgs.

Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcontrol_msgs.cmake or set
control_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
control_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

```
control_msgsConfig.cmake 
control_msgs-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 (find_package)
my_dynamixel_tutorial/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

So it is not identified as a package. How can I fix this? Is there any other simplest way to use this servo together with ROS?

And finally, should I create another node in order to get motor state and publish tf in order to use laser_assembler?

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100696/dynamixel_motor-with-catkin/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-11-13**:
Do you have the package control_msgs installed?

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2013-11-13**:
Thank you for your advice. I ignored that since I installed ROS full, so I was assuming everything was installed. Now I'm able to continue :)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-11-13**:
Cool. I'll post it as an answer, so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install the control_msgs package.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1